How to get client port (from the network layer) in Azure?
I have a web site which answers questions asked (often by young kids), this web site is by the government to educate kids and spread awareness.
Sometimes these kids asks questions which is life threatening for them or may be for others, in such cases we have a mandate to report to the police with user's home IP address and port number (NAT ports) so that police can prevent such events from happening.
We have a static web site made in Gatsby which is accessed via Azure CDN. This Gatsby web site makes request to backend APIs (C#, hosted in Azure APIM), which is where I want to have client port number. I can see the port number I need in Azure CDN logs (as 'clientPort_d') but Azure CDN has a latency of 1 hour between the request arrival and log written.
Is there any way to get the client port faster that this? What other Azure resources we can use (application gateway)?

The remote endpoint of the http connection.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/required-fqdn-endpoint?tabs=azure

Azure CDN logs contain the client port number,but there is a latency of 1 hr between the request arrival and log written. If you need to get the client port faster, you can use Azure Front Door or Azure Application Gateway. Both of these services can provide edge caching capabilities and routing features to divide static and dynamic content. By creating the appropriate routing rules, you can redirect traffic to static content. More complex caching scenarios can be implemented using the Azure CDN service to establish a full-fledged content delivery network for significant static content volumes

To get the client port number, you can configure your backend APIs to listen to the port specified in the process.env.PORT variable. In App Service on Windows, Node.js apps are hosted with IISNode, and your Node.js app should listen to the port specified in the process.env.PORT variable.
